# Final fields initialization order

Tags: java, jls

Here is some code that calls static method A.f() on class that is not initialized yet.
Can someone explain behavior of this code in terms of JLS?

```
class A {
    final static Object b = new B();
    final static int S1 = 1;
    final static Integer S2 = 2;

    static void f() {
        System.out.println(S1);
        System.out.println(S2);
    }
}

class B {
    static {
        A.f();
    }
}

public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        A.f();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
null
1
2
```

Comment: I guess everyone agrees that  the impressive part is the `null` one and that there is some precedence of primitive object initialization vs the non-primitive one

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`A.f()` in `App.main()` triggers initialization of class `A`.

All constant variables are initialized. The only constant variable is `S1`, which now is `1`.

Then, the other static fields are initialized in textual order. `b` is the first field, which triggers initialization of class `B`, which in turn calls `A.f()`. `S2` is simply `null` because it is not initialized yet. Initialization of `b` is now complete. Last but not least, `S2` is initialized to the `Integer` object `2`.

`S2` is not a constant variable because it is not of the primitive type `int` but of the reference type `Integer`. `S2 = 2;` is an auto-boxing shorthand for `S2 = Integer.valueOf(2);`.

> If a declarator in a field declaration has a variable initializer, then the declarator has the semantics of an assignment (§15.26) to the declared variable.
>
> […]
>
> Note that `static` fields that are constant variables (§4.12.4) are initialized before other `static` fields (§12.4.2). This also applies in interfaces (§9.3.1). Such fields will never be observed to have their default initial values (§4.12.5), even by devious programs.

[8.3.2. Field Initialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2)

> A *constant variable* is a `final` variable of primitive type or type `String` that is initialized with a constant expression (§15.28). Whether a variable is a constant variable or not may have implications with respect to class initialization (§12.4.1), binary compatibility (§13.1, §13.4.9), and definite assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment)).

[4.12.4. `final` Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

> A *constant expression* is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a `String` that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:
>
> - Literals of primitive type and literals of type `String`
>
> […]

[15.28. Constant Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

> For each class or interface C, there is a unique initialization lock `LC`. The mapping from C to `LC` is left to the discretion of the Java Virtual Machine implementation. The procedure for initializing C is then as follows:
>
> […]
>
> 6. Otherwise, record the fact that initialization of the `Class` object for C is in progress by the current thread, and release `LC`.
>
>    Then, initialize the `static` fields of C which are constant variables (§4.12.4, §8.3.2, §9.3.1).
>
> […]
>
> 9. Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

[12.4.2. Detailed Initialization Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)

> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is used:
>
> - Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10.2):
>
>   […]
>
>   - For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is `null`.

[4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

Comment: But how does this then relate to the "textual order" mentioned in Step 9 of [Section 12.4.2 Detailed Initialization Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Is your question why `S1` is initialized before `b`? `S1` is initialized in step 6 of said section.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this issue doesn't belong to `JLS`, but we have deal with `JVMS`.

On `Linking` stage before `resolution` process there is [Preparation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.2) substage, which involves:

> creating the static fields for a class or interface and initializing
>   such fields to their default values

and more:

> explicit initializers for static fields are executed as part of
>   initialization (§5.5), not preparation

while [initialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5) includes:

> The execution of any one of the Java Virtual Machine instructions new

Initializing of primitive types includes writing their initial value. For reference type fields their default value is `null` because before [Resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3) substage jvm doesn't "know" which class is associated to apropriate symbolic reference name of a class.